# How to schedule large numbers of user-generated job that will run once in future with aws sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to use aws sqs to store jobs created by users. Each of the jobs are supposed to run at a specific time designated by users. For example, a typical job could be that the user want to send an email 10 days later. Ideally I will setup workers who should only be able to see the job after 10 days so the worker can execute immediately and move on to next job.

I know the jobs can remain invisible for workers up to 15 min but the time between job creation and expected job execution can be several months.

If the job cannot remain invisible, it might still be doable if the queue can behave like a priority queue. But seems that's not an option neither.

I wonder if sqs can fit this use case? Or what would be a better solution than sqs?

Answer (score 2):

SQS is a terrible fit for your use case. I would look into scheduling a Lambda task to run at the scheduled times that you need.